# Laravel cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable put @ as prefix or filter it in route

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slug, laravel-route

Laravel version 7.0, I am using [cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)  package.

What I want is to put `@` as prefix to the username.

I included Sluggable trait in User model and set like this.

```
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'username' => [
            'source' => 'name',
            'separator' => '',
            'onUpdate' => true
        ]
    ];
}
```

Now what I want is `https://mywebsite.com/@username` url shows user profile.

I think either we can put `@` as prefix in sluggable package or we can detect it in laravel route.

Can anyone suggest me better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the better solution.

I could add @ in laravel route easily.

```
Route::get('/@{username}', 'HomeController@user')->name('user.index');
```

We can save username without @ and put @ as prefix in laravel route.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to try eloquent-sluggable's [`method`](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#method) and generate the prefixed slug there (i.e. in the `@username` format) instead of keeping `@` as a part of the route.

The rationale behind this advice is that when you generate and store `@` within the slug itself and not the route (as I understood you were questioning which one is better) you ease the task of referencing users with `@` symbol as you only need to query matching entries and you do not need to care about making transformations (for example, to prefix the `username` with `@` when generating a link) back and forth.

**Update: added basic example for `method` to prefix with username with `@`**

It is a basic example that shows how to prefix the user with `@`. Make sure to add spaces handling yourself in case usernames may contain those.

```php
  return [
    'username' => [
      ...,
      'method' => function ($username, $separator) {
        // example from docs: strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', $separator, $string));
        return "@{$username}";
      },
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: Could you suggest some code to use `method`? Thanks

Comment: @lovecoding-laravel I updated the answer to include a small example. I think you can go on with improving it to match your requirements.